# Best way to have every process send a set of data and receive data from all other processes in parallel. MPI

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm trying to, every so often in my program, have every process send a set of data that every other process needs. This said process also needs data from every other process. My thinking would be to broadcast a message to send the data. And then have a series of receives to receive data from all other processes. This seems very messy and the number of processes would need to be known when writing the code. I'm thinking there must be a better way to do this.

I'm writing my program in C using MPI.

Comment: It looks like MPI_Allgather would be a good option for me. Could this be used in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MPI_Allgather` is the right tool for the job here. Each process has some data that it distributes to all other processes. If you need pointers on how to use it (and other collective calls), there are some good tutorials online:

- http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-scatter-gather-and-allgather/
- http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_Allgather.html

Comment: Oh one question. Is MPI_Barrier implied with this function call?

Comment: Yes. Allgather is a synchronizing collective.